# If G is a finite group and $x \in G$, there is an integer n $\geq 1$ such that $x^n = e$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let G be a finite group. Show that, given $x \in G$, there is an integer n $\geq 1$ such that $x^n = e$.

I'm trying to use the info that is finite, but I can't find a way. For instance, if G is a multiplicative group and G = {-1,1} the affirmation is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $x \in G$. If $x = e$ then set $n = 1$. Suppose that $x \neq e$. Since $G$ is finite the sequence $x^{n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ has duplicates. Suppose that $x^{m} = x^{n}$ for distinct $m$ and $n$ with $m < n$. Then $x^{n - m} = e$.

Comment: Could you explain it a little more? Why is $x^n$ a sequence? Isn't just a exponentiation? In the last part, why is $x^{n-m}=e$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The sequence is $x^1,x^2,x^3,\ldots,x^n,x^{n+1},\ldots$. Multiply both sides of the equation $x^m=x^n$ by $x^{-m}$ to get $x^{n-m}=e$.

Comment: Hmm, it was right before my eyes, thanks Derek. One last question relative to the notation, assume an operation *, my book said that sometimes the symbol can be omitted, meaning, a*b can be written as ab. My doubt is, is $x^n$ the regular exponentiation (e.g. $ 2^{3} = 8 $) or * applied n times (e.g. $ x^{n} = x*x*x...*x $), because in both ways the proof works.

Comment: Derek has a good explanation of the sequence and the multiplication.  $x^{n}$ I mean $x * x \cdots * x$ where there are $n$ $x$'s.

Comment: Feels good to finally understand the whole question! I was stuck in it thinking it was the regular exponentiation. Thanks very much Jay!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: This might be little too late but I would appreciate it if someone could explain why we need the ''...has duplicates'' remark at all.

Comment: @Egbusa It might be that infinitely many of the $x^n$'s are different. I was trying trying to say that can't happen. Use the pigeon hole principle.

Answer (score 0):

It's always nice to have multiple ways to prove something, so I will add an alternate method, although it does not necessarily use the fact that G is finite.

If $\mathbf G$  is a finite group and $x$ is an element of $\mathbf G$, then the cyclic group generated by $x$, or $<x>$, is a subgroup. A subgroup must contain an identity element $e$; otherwise, it would not be a subgroup. By the definition of $<x>$, there exists an integer *n* such that $x^n=y,\space \forall \space y\in <x>$. In particular, $e \in <x>$, so there must be an integer $n$ such that $x^n=e$ is true.

But to show that n is non zero then we need to go back to the fact that the subgroup is finite and use the pigeonhole principle